# jTweetsAnywhere searchParams

Tags: javascript, twitter

Is it possible to only get tweets form the HowToEnjoyBLFST stream, those with #HowToEnjoyBLFST and those with @HowToEnjoyBLFST with the searchParams function in jTweetsAnywhere?

In other words no other tweets with mention of HowToEnjoyBLFST in them.

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested it was done with a simple query

```
q=%40HowToEnjoyBLFST+OR+%23HowToEnjoyBLFST+OR+from:HowToEnjoyBLFST
```